# Change application name when language inside the app is changed

Tags: android, localization

I have the app that is in Serbian and English language. Inside the app user can pick the language. Problem is that I want to have a different name (in app drawer) for different languages. If a phone is in English, app name will be shown in English, but if a user changes a language, the name stays in English. Is it possible to change app name on language change?

Comment: "Problem is that I want to have a different name (in app drawer) for different languages" -- by "app drawer", do you mean the home screen and its launcher?

Comment: Yes, name in launcher's app drawer and on home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside the app user can pick the language

The key word there is "inside". What you are describing is something internal to your app. No other apps — including the home screen — know anything about this.

> Problem is that I want to have a different name (in app drawer) for different languages

AFAIK, there is no reliable way to do this.

An unreliable way to do this is to have two different activities in your manifest, each with the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, one with the English name in `android:label` and one with the Serbian name in `android:label`. One of these will be set with `android:enabled="false"`, so the other one is the one that shows up in the home screen at the outset. When the user changes the language inside your app, you use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to toggle which of those two activities is the enabled one.

(you should be able to accomplish the same thing with one `<activity>` and one `<activity-alias>` rather than two activities, but I have not used `<activity-alias>` all that much)

The problem with this is two-fold:

1. Not all home screens will detect this change in component status. Some will update their launcher ("app drawer") to reflect the change. Others will not, until the device is rebooted.
2. This only affects things like the home screen that are looking for launcher activities. This will not affect things like the list of installed apps, or notifications, the overview screen/recent-tasks list, and anything else that relies upon the *application* name, which you cannot change.

Another option would be for you to create a home screen [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) to launch your app, as you can control whether that app widget contains English or Serbian text. However, the user has to add that to their home screen themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to implement the string.xml for desire language. 
You just need to add another string.xml file in: `values-es/strings.xml` and instead of es your desired language.
Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#UseString) and it will automatically use what you want.

EDIT:

A guide in this [link](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-localization-at-runtime/)

Basically you need a method like below which accepts the locale as String (like 'en' for English, 'hi' for hindi), configure the locale for your App and refresh your current activity to reflect the change in language. The locale you applied will not be changed until you manually change it again.

```
 public void setLocale(String lang) { 
Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = myLocale; 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
startActivity(refresh); 
finish();
}
```

Make sure you imported following packages:

```
import java.util.Locale; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.res.Configuration; 
import android.content.res.Resources; 
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
```

add in manifest to activity 
    `android:configChanges="locale|orientation"`

Or maybe another way could be to store the language type in a preference screen, and then check if the preference is for a language or another, and change manually what you want

Comment: Yes, but that will not work if phone language is e.g. English, and app language is Serbian. In that case, I want to have Serbian app name on home screen, but it will be English.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: This is still not going to change the name of the app on the HomeScreen of Android. Please take a look at first answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you  meant that, I thought you meant the name inside the app, like on the app bar.